# How to create a data model in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, xcode8

I'm new to a core data, I want to create a data modal for an events. I have two entity,

Entity 1: **Event** with attribute eventName, eventId and eventTime. JSON look like,

```
{
    {
        "eventName": "Dance",
        "eventId": 113,
        "eventTime": 10-10-2017
    },
    {
        "eventName": "Painting",
        "eventId": 113,
        "eventTime": 10-10-2017
    },
    ........
    ........
    {
        "eventName": "Swimming",
        "eventId": 111,
        "eventTime": 10-10-2017
    }
}
```

Entity 2. **EventKeywordsAndIds** with attribute keyword and eventIds. JSON look like,

```
{
    "keyword": "aaa",
    "eventIds": [
      119,
      111,
      112,
      116
    ]
  },
  {
    "keyword": "aab",
    "eventIds": [
      114,
      183,
      111,
      033,
      113
    ]
  }
```

I have created "Entity 1" easily, because it's very simple and straight forward. My question is,

1. How to create "Entity 2" attributes in the data model
2. How to parse the JSON value and store in it and
3. How to create a relationship between two entities.

Any help?

Comment: Read first: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/KeyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH30-SW1

Answer (score 0):

> How to create "Entity 2" attributes in the data model?

To do this, you need to create another entity called `EventID` first. Add an attribute called `id` and make it of type `Integer32`. After that, create a "to many" relationship from `Entity2` to `EventID` by clicking on the "+" in the relationships section This kind of answers your third question at the same time. Here is a picture of what you should have:

[image]

Note that you should select "To Many" for the "Type" property on the right there. There are also other properties you should consider setting.

> How to parse the JSON value and store in it?

This should be easy if you use SwiftyJSON.

Comment: This answer is correct, except I'm not sure there's value in creating a separate `EventID` entity. I would make the second entity `Keyword` with a single string property and then have a many-to-many relationship between `Event` and `Keyword`.

Comment: @DaveWeston you can create many to many relationships in core data? I thought I read somewhere that I can't.

Comment: Sure you can: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW8